# Postgresql get keys from nested array of objects in JSONB field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-json

Here' a dummy data for the jsonb column

```
{
"address": [
{
  "country": "US",
  "extension": [
    {
      "extension": [
        {
          "valueDecimal": -71.024638,
          "url": "latitude"
        },
        {
          "url": "longitude",
          "valueDecimal": 42.082543
        }
      ],
      "url": "url1"
    }
  ],
  "postalCode": "02301",
  "city": "Brockton"
},
{
  "country": "US",
  "extension": [
    {
      "extension": [
        {
          "valueDecimal": -71.024638,
          "url": "latitude"
        },
        {
          "url": "longitude",
          "valueDecimal": 42.082543
        }
      ],
      "url": "url2"
    }
  ],
  "postalCode": "02301",
  "city": "Brockton"
}
]
}
```

I want to get something like, `address->'extension'->'extension'->'valueDecimal'` but it only works with the json but it is an array of JSON data...my expecting output -

```
[-71.024638, -71.024638]
```

I'm able to get a first extension(i.e first array of JSON ) with the below query

```
SELECT elems.value  FROM "patient", jsonb_array_elements(resource -> 'extension') AS elems;
```

so the problem is that I'm not able to get inner 'extension'(It is inside the extension object) data. Any help will be Helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may cross join multiple levels of `jsonb_array_elements`

```
SELECT json_agg(elems3->>'valueDecimal') as latitudes
    FROM patient
 cross join jsonb_array_elements(resource ->'address'  ) AS elems
 cross join jsonb_array_elements(elems ->'extension')  AS elems2
 cross join jsonb_array_elements(elems2 ->'extension') AS elems3
 where elems3->>'url' = 'latitude'
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=bd489606edf19d6aff9164a35862c2fc)

This may be slower for large records although there are ways to improve performance. A recommended option is to redesign and normalize your table to store values separately as columns in their corresponding tables and use `JSON` only where there's no other way to deal with the data.

Comment: Is there any way to index this nested data?

Comment: @Jitendra : Yes, as I said, there are options, for e.g  using `GIN` index. You may explore them.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it is working for nested json object but it is not working for multilevel array of json object. Something like this - `CREATE INDEX idxginp ON patient USING gin ((resource->'maritalStatus'->'coding') jsonb_path_ops);`